# XML validation: decimal attribute value starting with a space

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have developed a small `C#` script that opens an `XLS` file, parses it and creates a list of `XML` files validating them against an `XSD` file.

I've tried to upload these validated files to a third-party online service (the same company that gave me the documentation/xsd stuff)  and one generated file is not being accepted because **NOT VALID**.

The file is not accepted because it has a space at the beginning of a decimal value in a node attribute; removing this space fixes the problem.

I have created a simple test case where XDocument [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.validate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method validates the XML with the extra-space without any problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace TestParser {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string xsdMarkup =
            @"<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
                <xs:element name='option'>
                    <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base='xs:string'>
                        <xs:attribute name='value' type='xs:decimal'>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>";
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));

        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument(
            new XElement("option","test", new XAttribute("value", " 423423")
            ));    
        Console.WriteLine("Validating doc1");
        bool errors = false;
        doc1.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                                        errors = true;
                                    }, true);
        Console.WriteLine("doc1 {0}", errors ? "not valid" : "validated");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of doc1:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc1);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
Validating doc1
doc1 validated

Contents of doc1:
<option value=" 423423">test</option>
```

Is it correct that the C# XML Parser validates this XML?
Is it possible to force the Parser to be more picky about this formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading the XML spec correctly, leading whitespaces in attribute values are to be trimmed (as the .NET XML parser does):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize

"If the attribute type is not CDATA, then the XML processor MUST further process the normalized attribute value by discarding any leading and trailing space (#x20) characters [...]"

Comment: that's interesting thanks; the third-party adopted parser seems not doing any trim at all.

Answer (score 2):

`xs:decimal` is an XML Schema type (not a DTD type) and the [relevant part of the XML Schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace) is how whitespace applies to xs:decimal:

> whiteSpace is applicable to all
>   ·atomic· and ·list· datatypes. For all
>   ·atomic· datatypes other than string
>   (and types ·derived· by ·restriction·
>   from it) the value of whiteSpace is
>   collapse and cannot be changed by a
>   schema author

`xs:decimal` is not derived from `xs:string`, so the whitespace should be allowed and ignored. "Collapse" means to trim leading and trailing whitespace and to collapse internal runs into single space characters.